# On image click hide the image and display a div with transition

Tags: javascript, wordpress, css-transitions

I'm working on a search bar. First, the user will only be able to see the search icon. When the user clicks on the search icon then that search icon gets replaced with a div that contains a new search bar. I want that when the user click on the search icon the new div with a transition of 1 second in such a way that it looks like the new div was the expanded version of the search icon.

```
<img src="https://populusww.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/search.png" id="Search-Collapse" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="toggle_div_fun();">
    <br/><br/>

    <script>
        
        function toggle_div_fun() {
            debugger;
            document.getElementById("Search-Collapse").style.transition = "all 2s";
            debugger;
    var divelement = document.getElementById("Search-Collapse");
    var searchelement =document.getElementById("Search-Expand");
    var menusection =document.getElementById("menu-section");
    var searchsection =document.getElementById("search-section");
    if(divelement.style.display == 'none'){
        divelement.style.display = 'block';
        searchelement.style.display = 'none';
        menusection.style.width = '65%';
        searchsection.style.width = '15%';
        searchsection.style.marginTop = '30px';
    }
    else{
        divelement.style.display = 'none';
        searchelement.style.display = 'block';
        menusection.style.width = '65%';
        searchsection.style.width = '15%';
        searchsection.style.marginTop = '50px';
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you want exactly, you want to click on the image and hide it to show a div? or you want to click to show a search input?

Comment: I want that user clicks on search icon and a search input opens with a transition of 1 second

Comment: I answered with a detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Display did not work with transition, you can use `divelement.style.opacity = 0;` to hide your div with effect
and do not forget set opacity for initiate set `divelement.style.opacity = 1;`

something like this:

```html
<img src="https://populusww.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/search.png" id="Search-Collapse" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="toggle_div_fun();">
    <br/><br/>

    <script>
        document.onload = () => {
             document.getElementById("Search-Expand").style.transition = "all 2s";
             document.getElementById("Search-Collapse").style.transition = "all 2s";
             document.getElementById("Search-Collapse").style.opacity = 1;
              document.getElementById("Search-Expand").style.opacity = 1;
        }
        function toggle_div_fun() {
          
           
    var divelement = document.getElementById("Search-Collapse");
    var searchelement =document.getElementById("Search-Expand");
    var menusection =document.getElementById("menu-section");
    var searchsection =document.getElementById("search-section");
    if(divelement.style.display == 'none'){
        divelement.style.display = 'block';
        searchelement.style.display = 'none';
        menusection.style.width = '65%';
        searchsection.style.width = '15%';
        searchsection.style.marginTop = '30px';
    }
    else{
        divelement.style.display = 'none';
        searchelement.style.display = 'block';
        menusection.style.width = '65%';
        searchsection.style.width = '15%';
        searchsection.style.marginTop = '50px';
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using CSS opacity in JavaScript simple event listener;
Check this detailed code below if you don't understand any things let me know and I'll try to explain it to you :D

HTML:

```
<img src="https://populusww.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/search.png" id="Search-Collapse" style="cursor: pointer;">
<br>
<input type="text" id="Search-Input" placeholder="search query" />
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: red;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

JS:

```
var searchIcon = document.querySelector('img');
var inputSearch = document.getElementById('Search-Input');
inputSearch.style.opacity = 0;
inputSearch.style.transition = "opacity 1s"

searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function(){

  if(inputSearch.style.opacity == 0 || inputSearch.style.opacity == ''){
    inputSearch.style.opacity = 1;

  }
  else {
  
   inputSearch.style.opacity = 0;

  }

});
```

and here is a working example on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Mohcinbn/tva7hz9L/24/)